# How to undo a clear:both in css?

Tags: css

I have a clear:both written for an html tag and I want to undo it at a particular location. Please guide me if this is possible. If possible then how? Thanks.

```
img{
clear:both;
}
```

Now I want to remove the clear:both for a `img` tag I am placing.

Comment: What do you mean by undo, and what does your html look like? These are important things for people to have in order to answer a question.

Comment: `selector { clear:none; }`

Comment: Can you please post it as an answer. Both of your comments have solved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

To "undo" in CSS terms means for the rule to be *more specific* than the one you're trying to *overrule*. To do that for an inline `style` attribute you'll need to use an `!important` exception, such as:

```
<selector> {
  clear: none !important;
}
```

However, using `!important` is [not recommended as good practice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity):

> Using !important is bad practice because it makes debugging hard since
>   you break the natural cascading in your stylesheets.

- It often implies that you're not properly implementing (or understanding) specificity.
- In larger projects you'll often see this used on classes such as `.hidden` where the semantics of the class are obvious, and you don't want them to be burdened by the normal rules of specificity.

Answer (score 0):

First add an `id` next to the specific image or a `class` if many

```
<img src="https://../x.jpg" alt="" id="thisOne" class="thoseOnes">
```

Then in your css:

```
img#thisOne {
   clear:none;
}
```

or

```
img.thoseOnes {
   clear:none;
}
```